# Custom Redirect after registration in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, user-registration

After a user registers using WooCommerce's registration form, I want to redirect them to a custom page, such as my other website, instead of the `my-account` page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'ps_wc_registration_redirect',10); 
function ps_wc_registration_redirect( $redirect_to ) {  
    $redirect_to ="http://example.com";
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

The hook above successfully redirects users when the destination is a page on the current site, but when the redirect location is off of the current site, it does not work.

Is there any other hook available after the user registration redirection occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, WooCommerce uses WordPress' `wp_safe_redirect()` which does not allow redirects to external hosts. In order to get around this, we must add our desired host to the whitelist. The whitelist can be modified using the `allowed_redirect_hosts` which has been demonstrated below:

```
/**
 * Adds example.com to the list of allowed hosts when redirecting using wp_safe_redirect()
 *
 * @param array       $hosts An array of allowed hosts.
 * @param bool|string $host  The parsed host; empty if not isset.
 */
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'wpse_allowed_redirect_hosts', 10, 2 );
function wpse_allowed_redirect_hosts( $hosts, $host ) {
    $hosts[] = 'example.com';

    return $hosts;
}
```

Use the code above along with your original code (customizing the host as needed) to allow WooCommerce users to be redirected to an external domain after completing the registration process.

Comment: Thank you for you response

add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'ps_wc_registration_redirect',10); 
function ps_wc_registration_redirect( $redirect_to ) {  
    $redirect_to ="http://example.com";
    return $redirect_to;
}
This code is used to redirect after woocommerce registration how can i use your code into the "woocommerce_registration_redirect" hook.

Comment: Use your original code in addition to what I posted. `wpse_allowed_redirect_hosts()` whitelists the domain and `ps_wc_registration_redirect()` sets the location for the redirect.

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'bryce_wc_register_redirect');
function bryce_wc_register_redirect( $redirect_to ) {
 $redirect_to="http://zmanager.zenvus.com";
 return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', 'wpse_allowed_redirect_hosts',10,2 );
 function wpse_allowed_redirect_hosts(  $redirect ) {
    $redirect[] = "http://zmanager.zenvus.com";
    return $redirect;
}
i have put this code like this but it not working. can you please help me 

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Please [edit your original question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/271964/edit) and add the code you're using there and explain what *not working* means exactly. It's hard to read code in comments. BTW, I did test the code before posting and it worked for me. We'll get it!

Comment: Thank you for your support
yeah i have customize code and  its working!!

Comment: Glad to hear, @KajalSolanki. You got it!

Answer (score 0):

try setting the function as below, also there is no need of parameter to the function if you are manually setting the link in the function

```
function custom_registration_redirect_after_registration() {
    return home_url('/post_slug_or_page_slug');
}
add_action('woocommerce_registration_redirect', 'custom_registration_redirect_after_registration', 2);
```